# artifact:pom command not recognized in one workspace but not another

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ant

I have 2 workspaces in which I am trying to use an ANT build to build an ear file. The one workspace uses 3 different projects to build the ear.  I needed to create a single workspace to create the same ear.  I migrated all of the source code, properties files, etc. to build this ear.  The compile is breaking on this line:

```
<artifact:pom id="parent-pom" file="./mvn/parent/pom.xml" >
        <profile id="${deploy.name}" />
</artifact:pom>
```

I have the pom file in the folder in the project.
The error is:
**Problem: failed to create task or type antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant:pom**

This build file has the artifact added at the top of the file:

```
<project name="Ant XML Library for Deploying" default="usage" basedir="." xmlns:artifact="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant">
```

The 2 workspaces are using the same compute and same Eclipse environment.  I searched the other projects for the jar, **maven-ant-tasks.jar** but it is not any of the projects in the workspace that is correctly building the ear file.
The only jar files that are in a **lib** folder in one of the projects are these:

```
ant-contrib.jar
cm-anttasks.jar
jsch-0.1.41.jar
log4j-1.2.8.jar
```

I tried adding these to the workspace that is not working but it does not work.

Any ideas as to what I need to add to the workspace?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added maven-ant-tasks.jar to my project and it now recognizes the commands.
However, my initial workspace did not need this jar included into the project.  It recognized the commands.